# Openoffice didn't install correctly, how do I remove it?

Tags: installation, uninstall, openoffice.org

I attempted to install openoffice with the packages that the openoffice site automatically got for me which were incorrect; RPM files insead of DEB files. The problem is after attempting to install the wrong files and the going back a trying to reinstall with the right files Ubuntu thinks there is already a working version of openoffice, which there isn't. I tried to remove it the way you would if it was the correct installation and working, that hasn't worked. So is there any way to remove every thing related to openoffice so I can try again?

Comment: Can you mention exactly how did you install the RPM files? What went wrong? And how did you "try to remove it the way you would if it was the correct installation"? What commands did you use for all of these, and did they give you any errors? What's the output of `dpkg -l | grep openoffice`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to install aptitude first on your Ubuntu system. Run this command in Terminal to install aptitude.

```
    sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Once that finishes, you can purge openoffice and remove it completely with this command:

```
    sudo aptitude purge openoffice.org
```

`aptitude` will remove all dependencies that were included with openoffice. This is why we are using this instead of `apt-get`.